# Why do most centrifugal fans found in laptops have tiny blades?

Tags: everyday-life, aerodynamics

If you were to use a centrifugal axial fan instead, won't you be able to achieve higher flow rates and better pressures? It seems like the efficiency of these motors are very low.

[image: Typical centrifugal fan]

Comment: This appears to be more of an engineering question than a physics one.

Comment: @Chair sure there is something physics could say about the efficiency, but that's not really what the question is, it's about the design choices of engineers & why a different option wasn't selected.

Comment: @Chair answers do **not** make a question on-topic. You can suggest to OP to edit the question to be more about physics than design choices (engineering), then it'd go through normal review process. Until then, it should remain closed (imo)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78978/discussion-between-chair-and-kyle-kanos). I'm deleting my previous comments from this thread, but they'll remain in the chat.